# Creating a database in Mongo: can't connect, get "connect failed"

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a new database in Mongo. However, I'm having trouble connecting:

```
:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.6.5
connecting to: test
Tue Dec 21 18:16:25 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 (anon):1154
exception: connect failed
```

How can I connect to mongo in order to create a new database? Alternatively, can I create a new database from the command line?

Slightly surprisingly, the [Mongo docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Databases) don't seem to cover how to create a database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In order to open Mongo JavaScript shell, a Listener should be initialized first.

So, first run mongod.exe before running mongo.exe. Both are in the same location(/bin).

There is no separate commands to create a db in mongodb. Just type "use dbname;" in console. Now you have created a db of the name 'dbname'. Now, if you type 'show databases' you cannot see the db name you just created. Because, mongo will not create any db, util you create collection and insert a document into that collection.

Hope this is useful to you!

Answer (score 24):

1. cd /var/lib/mongodb/
2. remove mongod.lock file from this folder
3. sudo start mongodb  (in console)
4. mongo (in console)

   And it runs fine.

Comment: @kaushik Oh  thanks, that saved my day ! This worked on my ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Worked for me. Why did this happen in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

First you'll need to run mongod on one terminal. Then fire up another terminal and type mongo. This shall open the mongo shell. You also need to create /data/db/ where mongo will store your databases.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to run mongod (the daemon) before you can use mongo (the client), it's easiest to just run it in another shell; These should be in your path if mongo is installed correctly. After that the docs should get you through creating and editing dbs and collections.

Answer (score 0):

Just try following commands in given order :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

sudo mongod --repair

sudo service mongodb start

sudo service mongodb status
```