# Can't connect to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm newbie about node.js and mongodb.

I have already installed mongodb, but I can't connect to mongodb.

This is my error:

```
Huys-MacBook-Pro:~ huy$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.2
connecting to: test
Tue Jan  3 17:12:01 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MongoDB is not running, and I have a wild guess that your mistake is this one: [Trouble installing mongodb using Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522658/trouble-installing-mongodb-using-homebrew)

Create the path `/data/db` and then try to start MongoDB again. (run `mongod`)

Comment: yesterday,mongo ran but today it doesn't run... i checked folder `/data/db`, it's installed... So, what do i do to run my `mongo`.

Comment: could u give me an example app about use express and mongoose to login..? thank you so much.

Comment: @EnzoTran http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397977/how-to-do-authentication-with-node-js-express-and-mongoose

Comment: thank so much.. i'm really happy when receive your enthusiastic help from you. could you give me your skype to contact to get easier. It's my skype: `tranhoanghuy0905`.

Answer (score 6):

I also ran into this issue today. Mongo had been working fine up until this point. In case you try `sudo service mongodb start` and you find out the process is already running (`start/running, process xxxx`). The solution is:

Delete the lock file

`sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock`

and restart service again

`sudo service mongodb start`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check that your data folder exists : [mongo on Win](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Windows). That is

```
C:\> mkdir \data
C:\> mkdir \data\db
```

Comment: Great... if it was the proble, don't forget to accept the solution... so that other will be warned to not forget this mandatory step. Which from my POV, MUST have a dedicated error code, or at least meaningful error message

Answer (score 1):

if you are using windows version then

first run `mongod` in one `cmd` box

```
C:\> cd \my_mongo_dir\bin
C:\my_mongo_dir\bin> mongod
```

leave it open and now again tyep `cmd`  and do the below

```
:\> cd \my_mongo_dir\bin
C:\my_mongo_dir\bin> mongo
```

**[Reference](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Windows)**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem under xubuntu, had been using mongo for quite long, for some reason it could not start anymore reporting that very same error... in case anyone is in the same situation, the solution for me was to reinstall:

`apt-get autoremove mongodb`

`apt-get install mongodb-server`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `mongod` is not running. Try to run `mongod` from your console

see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo for full document

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Yesterday was working perfectly mongo on my mac, but today doesn't, I solved just typing in a terminal command.

`brew update`

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

Replace the /var/lib/mongodb with your dbpath

`sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --repair sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --journal`

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

1. Open two terminal windows
2. In one window start "sudo mongod"
   at the end of the response you should have:

> 2015-08-29T11:38:18.009-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for
>   connections on port 27017

3. Other window type mongo, and everthing should be working.